# Angles in a triangle whose sides are three consecutive primes

Tags: geometry

What is the least possible size of an angle in a triangle whose sides are three consecutive primes? And the largest?

Comment: Do you mean $$3,5,7$$?

Comment: Please show your thoughts about the question. Do we allow the degenerated triangle with sides $2,3,5$? Which is the smallest / biggest angle in the triangle with sides $3,5,7$ and/or $5,7,11$ and/or $7,11,13$ ? Some minimal effort is always welcome... (A potential answerer will have a simpler situation to type an answer, when the level of an expected solution thus becomes clear...)

Comment: Since cosine is decreasing for increasing angle you can use the cosine rule and find the largest/smallest cosine.

Comment: Of all "proper" triangles whose three sides have lengths that are three consecutive primes, such as 17, 19, and 23, which has the smallest angle?

Comment: 5,7,11 seems to have the smallest angle but how to prove?

Comment: It is like seeking the triplet that ratio of the sum of the two divided by the third has the largest value - close to 1